# How to map ports in Azure Container Instances via Terraform?

Tags: networking, azure, docker, containers, terraform

I have two containers in my container group on Azure using Azure Container Instances (ACI), one (container A) exposing ports `80` and `443` to the internet (reverse proxy), the other one (container B) also running on port `80`. How do I map container B's port `80` to a different port, say `8080`, so that the two containers don't collide with ports on `localhost` (on Azure, containers inside a container group can reach each other via localhost)?

I can't use `8080:80` because it needs to be a number and I don't see any other way to specify this. If I specify port `80` on container A, the reverse proxy just loops onto itself, essentially reverse proxying the reverse proxy (normally container B's port `80` would be reachable on localhost)

Example:

```
resource "azurerm_container_group" "main_containers" {
  name                = "containergroup"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name
  ip_address_type     = "public"
  dns_name_label      = local.dns_name_label
  os_type             = "Linux"
  restart_policy      = "Always"
  tags                = var.tags

  container {
    name   = "nextcloud"
    image  = "nextcloud"
    cpu    = "0.8"
    memory = "0.8"

    environment_variables = {
      MYSQL_DATABASE = azurerm_mariadb_database.nextcloud_database_db.name
      MYSQL_USER     = azurerm_mariadb_server.nextcloud_database.administrator_login
      MYSQL_HOST     = azurerm_mariadb_server.nextcloud_database.fqdn
    }

    secure_environment_variables = {
      MYSQL_PASSWORD = azurerm_mariadb_server.nextcloud_database.administrator_login_password
    }

    volume {
      name                 = azurerm_storage_share.nextcloud_storage_nextcloud_data_share.name
      mount_path           = "/var/www/html"
      storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.nextcloud_storage.name
      storage_account_key  = azurerm_storage_account.nextcloud_storage.primary_access_key
      share_name           = azurerm_storage_share.nextcloud_storage_nextcloud_data_share.name
    }

    ports {
      # This is what I want to do but it fails with:
      # Inappropriate value for attribute "port": a number is required.
      port = "8080:80"
      protocol = "TCP"
    }
  }

  container {
    name   = "reverse-proxy-https"
    image  = "caddy"
    cpu    = "0.2"
    memory = "0.2"
    commands = [
      "caddy", "reverse-proxy",
      "-from", local.public_domain_name,
      # this is where I would tell to reverse-proxy to 8080
      "-to", "localhost:8080",
    ]

    ports {
      port     = 80
      protocol = "TCP"
    }

    ports {
      port     = 443
      protocol = "TCP"
    }

    volume {
      name                 = azurerm_storage_share.nextcloud_storage_caddy_data_share.name
      mount_path           = "/data/caddy"
      storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.nextcloud_storage.name
      storage_account_key  = azurerm_storage_account.nextcloud_storage.primary_access_key
      share_name           = azurerm_storage_share.nextcloud_storage_caddy_data_share.name
    }

    volume {
      name                 = azurerm_storage_share.nextcloud_storage_caddy_config_share.name
      mount_path           = "/config/caddy"
      storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.nextcloud_storage.name
      storage_account_key  = azurerm_storage_account.nextcloud_storage.primary_access_key
      share_name           = azurerm_storage_share.nextcloud_storage_caddy_config_share.name
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This only applies to **some** images: You can use the `secret` volume type to overwrite directories in the container – example: `volume { secret = { "000-default.conf" = base64encode(<<-EOT <VirtualHost *:8080> ... </VirtualHost> EOT) } mount_path = "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled" }`. This is misusing the `secret` volume type – what it really does is mount "inline" files into the container. This allows for easy configuration without modifying the image.

Comment: Addendum to previous comment: It should be noted, that for nextcloud, just overwriting 000-default.conf is not enough. You need to do it for the entire apache2.conf and that means all files in /etc/apache2. Doable, but annoying.